# Socket io request getting blocked

Tags: reactjs, http, socket.io, ws

While connecting to my socket.io server from react app, request is getting blocked. Its working with localhost but when i am trying from VPS, its not working.

**From VPS:**

[image]

[image]

**From localhost:**

[image]

```
http://server_ip:8007/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling
```

above url returning valid response `0{"sid":"VaHqLXI5UVRRaeUAAAAV","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error ("mixed block") seems to say, you must connect using HTTPS to localhost when hosting files from an HTTPS server. Meaning, should use `wss://` instead of `ws://`. Or connect to your vps host using `http://` protocol not `https://`.